# Rails 3 Best way to have two different home pages based on login status

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, routes

First I tried to access the session variable in the routes.rb file and put a simple if statement.  If the user is logged in go to entry#index else go to landing#index.  However, routes.rb does not seem to have access to session variables.  I have session[:user_id] set and can use it to verify login status.  Is it best to set the logged out page as home in routes.rb and then redirect in that controller if the user is logged in or is there a better way that I don't know about?

Here is what I did in the controller for the logged out user home page.

```
     def index
    if User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
      redirect_to entry_url
    end
  end
```

It works fine but not sure if there are any issues with this or a better way.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The routes actually do have access to session variables. You can set a constraint to route logged in users to a different root like below:

```
# Logged in
constraints lambda { |req| !req.session[:user_id].blank? } do
    root :to => "entry#index", :as => "dashboard"
end

# Not logged in
root :to => "landing#index"
```

It's important to note two things: first that the order matters here; second that the constraint can be refactored into a one line route unless you plan to use the constraint further (which I always do).

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the constraints option.  I was not aware of this.  Are you aware of any drawbacks to handling this in the routes instead of letting it hit the controller.  The routes seem more efficient since it won't make a request and immediately redirect but not sure if I am not considering something.

Comment: In terms of performance, it should be faster since, as you correctly mention, it's skipping a step. To my knowledge, this is the best way to approach this situation.

Comment: Here is good post with a complete example of this http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it should be handled by your controller and not by your routes.

```
def index
  @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  if @user
    redirect_to entry_url
  else
    redirect_to landing_url
  end
end
```

Comment: I am assuming you are placing this in a "3rd" controller.  For example a routing controller whose only purpose is to check the login status and route to the appropriate page?  If so is there a reason that this approach is better than my current approach of setting the landing page as root and if they are logged in redirecting to the logged in page?  Thanks..

Comment: Any particular reason why you say it should be handled by the controller instead of the route?  It seems like if you can handle a route in the route.rb file you should do so?  Is there some drawback to Logan's solution I am not aware of?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: No need a "3rd" controller just for checking it. You could just make this verification in your `ApplicationController`, using a `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Upvoting for the explanation.  I can't think of a reason why I wouldn't want to do this in the routes since it is really a routing issue.  If you are aware of something please let me know.  Thanks again for the helpful response.